# Why do I have to run most applications on Windows 10 as Administrator?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a baffling but also seriously troublesome issue with file permissions on Windows 10 x64.

For some time now, if I try to run any application that accesses files in my profile then I need to use “Run as Administrator” to avoid permission errors that prevent the application from working.

This is baffling because my own user is an Administrator anyway and I have checked the files/folders in question and my Effective Access is Full Control.

I’m talking about files in my C:\Users\clancy\AppData folders like Local, LocalLow and Roaming.

I have tried a number of things like changing ownership of all files in C:\Users\clancy to me and also adding myself as a Full Control user to all the folders, sub folders and files but the problem remains.

I’m not entirely sure when this issue started happening but I do recall at one point changing from logging in as a standard admin user to using a Microsoft account but that may be a red herring.

This problem causes all manner of issues with apps just trying to read or write in my own profile folders so much so that I configure every shortcut on the task bar to Run as Administrator at all times.

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this and/or a way to fix it?

I am very reluctant to reinstall Windows as I have a large number of heavily personalised applications and the time to install them all again would be in the days (time off work I can’t afford).

Thanks,

-c

Comment: What happens if you disable UAC? Try also to [Disable SmartScreen](https://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-smartscreen-filter-windows10/).

Comment: Thanks. I’ve tried both of those suggestions but the issues remain.

Comment: Have you relocated this folder or used a symlink. asking if this is a simple folder on the hard disk?

Comment: I haven’t relocated it and it’s not a symlink. All I have done to try to fix the issue is in my original question.

Comment: Run some checks: chkdsk and [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for your continued help. I ran both of those commands and no errors were reported.

Comment: Try next [DISM](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/03/16/use-dism-to-fix-issues-sfc-cant/).

Comment: Thanks @harrymc - DISM also reports no issues.

Comment: Last try before things start getting serious: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc Yes - the same issues occur in Safe Mode too.

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "logging in as a standard admin user" means logging in as %computername%\clancy. Create and try a new "cloud" user to see if the problems happen there, too; same with a new local admin user. But even if these work, moving your stuff to a new account is not easy.

File location virtualization may be part of your problem. If a program wants to write to a protected location, it will be redirected to your user profile and get a "permission" error at that place. Allow write access to your profile to (local) admins. (This is a bit more complicated than I can tell from memory.)

Note: when Windows NT says "access denied", it means "something went wrong, but I don't know if you are allowed to get any information about this object, so I will always act like it is a permission problem." Yes, it has been this bad since over 25 years.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. Now I log in as a "cloud" user with a Microsoft account but initially I just used the name Clancy to log in (no email address). I can't help but think that this is the root of the problem but don't know how to fix it. And as you say, even if I create another account, moving everything over is going to be very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is strange and I don't see how to analyze the case, except that it
looks like a problem with Windows itself.

I suggest returning all Windows components to a known state by doing
[In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

This operation is exactly the same as doing a Windows major update, so will
keep your data, apps and almost all Windows settings.

Take the same precautions as before a Windows major update, including backups.

Comment: Thanks. Someone suggested that the issues are related to Group Policies. Is that a possibility? If yes, which policies need investigation?

Comment: I don't know of any such Group Policy.